# XGBoost with Java - Problem loading boosters previosuly saved as ByteArray[]

Tags: java, machine-learning, xgboost

I'm trying to save/load booster objects into a database, hence rather than saving into files in the HDD, I'm saving/loading as byte[]. But for now, forget about the database as I'm only interested in converting the boosters to byte[], and then retrieving the boosters back from the byte[].

To save, I have a list of Boosters:

```
List<Booster> boosters = <Initialised somewhere else>;

for (Booster booster : model.getBoosters()) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
    booster.saveModel(out);
    out.close();
    boostersAsByte.add(bos.toByteArray());
}

return boostersAsbyte;
```

Then later on I'm trying to retrieve those boosters from the saved byte[]:

```
List<Booster> boosters = new ArrayList<>();

for (byte[] boosterAsByte : boostersAsbyte) {
    boosters.add(XGBoost.loadModel(new ByteArrayInputStream(boosterAsByte)));
}

return new boosters;
```

I am getting this annoying error:

```
ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.java.XGBoostError: [10:21:35] /xgboost/src/gbm/gbm.cc:20: Unknown gbm type
```

I have tried saving/restoring boosters from files in the HDD and it works; but for my specific solution I need to do things with byte[] to save those bytes into a DB.

Any help would be massively appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have saved the booster as an Object (ObjectOutputStream) then you have to read it as an Object (ObjectInputStream) via the ByteArrayInputStream. Example

```
List<Booster> boosters = new ArrayList<>();

for (byte[] boosterAsByte : boostersAsbyte) {
    boosters.add(XGBoost.loadModel(new 
     ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(boosterAsByte))));
}

return new boosters;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Your answer led me to the right solution, which I will post as another answer. Much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. It seems ObjectInputStream requires an InputStream and not byte[] to be initialised; but you gave me the right tip: I do not need to use the ObjectOutputStream and the initial loop be:

```
for (Booster booster : model.getBoosters()) {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        booster.saveModel(bos);
        boostersAsByte.add(bos.toByteArray());
    }
}
```

This way everything works :-)

Comment: Thank for the feedback. I know that ObjectInputStream requires an InputStream. The example is just to give you an idea how the Object-IO mechanism works.